# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY when editing an Order

Tags: sharing, dmlexception

When editing an Order (either through the UI or via an Apex program that does DML), I get

```
First exception on row 0 with id 801.... INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY insufficient access rights on object id: []
```

I can edit other orders, why not this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Answering to add to KB of these often inscrutable errors.*

There could be several reasons but in our org, here was the issue:

**OWD**:

- Account and Contact: Private
- Order: Controlled by parent

**Account sharing rule**:

- RecordType `Foo`: Shared Read/Write with Group A
- RecordType `Bar`: Shared Read/Write with Group B

**Users/Ownership**

- Running User: Alice
- Order's Owner: Bob
- Order's Account Owner: Cary
- Order's Account's RecordType: `Foo`
- Running user's group membership: `Group B`

**Running user permissions**

- View All on Order
- Modify All on Account
- Modify on Order (but not Modify All)

> ANALYSIS

- Edit access to an Order is controlled by Parent.
- Neither the Order nor its parent Account was owned by the running user
- Modify All on Account *does not* extend downward implicitly as Modify All on Order
- Although Edit access to the Account was extended R/W via a sharing rule to members of Group A (because Account was record type `Foo`), the running user was not a member of Group A and hence could not edit the Order because the running user was not shared R/W to the order's Account.

> SOLUTION

- Grant edit access to the Order's Account to the running user (say, via manual sharing or Account Criteria-based sharing rules)

Comment: +1 *This* is how one debugs a sharing problem. Often, just seeing the steps others take to resolve an issue can help with the oft-confusing maze that is sharing.

Comment: @sfdcfox problem made harder because Sharing button wasn't enabled on Account layout :-(