# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY Error on Order Items deletion, even though I am System Administrator

Tags: permissions, sharing, delete, crud, orderitem

Even though I have a System Administrator profile assigned to me, and have the CRUD permissions on the Order Line Item Object, I am receiving the below error when I try to delete the Order Item records through DML Operation in my apex class.

```
System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 8022M00000ANsKKQA1; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, insufficient access rights on object id: []
```

I have written the Apex Class as **"Without sharing"** to avoid any conflict related to sharing rules. But still, I am receiving this error. Can anyone please let me know why this may be happening. I am calling this class from an ****after update** trigger** Also, I am inserting customer history records using the same class too. The apex class is as below.

```
public without sharing class LineItemHistoryRecordCreation {
    public LineItemHistoryRecordCreation() {}

    public void createLineItemHistoryRecord(List<OrderItem> ordItemList) {
        List<Id> oliIdList = new List<Id>();

        List<History__c> historyList = new List<History__c>();
        for(OrderItem oli : ordItemList) {
            oliIdList.add(oli.Id);

            History__c his          = new History__c();
            his.Change_Log__c       = 'Order Product record deleted-OrderNumber ' + oli.OrderId + '-' + oli.Id + '-' + oli.OB_Order_ID__c;
            his.History_Type__c     = 'Order Product-Deleted';
            his.History_DateTime__c = DateTime.now();
            his.Record_Name__c      = oli.Id;
            his.Prior_Value__c        = 'Active';
            his.New_Value__c        = 'Deleted';
            historyList.add(his);
        }

        insert historyList;

        List<OrderItem> oliList = [SELECT Id FROM OrderItem WHERE Id IN :oliIdList];

        System.debug('order List akki' + oliList);
        if(!oliList.isEmpty()) {
            delete oliList;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with understanding and solving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly related https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/274930/2602 - CRUD on OLI depends on sharing rules for parent Order and Order's parent Account; Is `his.Record_Name__c` a lookup field or a text field?  If lookup, this won't work

Comment: Once you delete OLI, it might be trying to update other related aprent/child records. See if you are getting error because it is trying to perform DML operation on other object.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce enforces certain system-level validations that cannot be invalidated, even by a System Administrator. You haven't specified when the trigger runs, but my intuition tells me this is an `after delete` trigger, and the line the error occurs on is `insert historyList;`. The line that causes this problem is             `his.Record_Name__c = oli.Id;`.

The reason why is because the record is deleted. You can't associate a record to a deleted record, even if you're a system administrator. The ID is considered invalid. Further, even if this *did* work, it would still not have the desired effect, because the field would be nulled out immediately after saving, since the original record no longer exists (though, it would be restored if the deleted record could also be undeleted somehow).

Also, presuming this is an after delete trigger, we can also therefore remove the `oliList` part entirely; you can't query the records, because they're already deleted, and you wouldn't be able to delete them, because they're already deleted.

Your best bet would be to have `Record_Name__c` point to an Order, so you could at least track the deleted items at the Order level. What you're trying to do here is simply not supported in any way.

Comment: The trigger that runs is the "after update" and the line that's causing the error is "delete oliList" which I am using to delete the Order Line Items. Could this be happening because of the Role Hierarchy? Could this error be possibly showing up because the Owner of line item records has a higher role than what I have been assigned?

Comment: @AkshayVasu a record already being deleted is already deleted. You don't need to delete it again. It has nothing to do with the Role Hierarchy.

Comment: No, the record isn't already deleted. What I am trying to do is, when a particular status is updated on line item, I am sending those records to this class through After Update Trigger. And I am creating custom history records (Different Custom Objects) for those records. And then going ahead and trying to delete those line items. But when I try to delete that, the above-mentioned error is being thrown. These line items are visible in the related list without getting deleted. I am sorry, if I am still not clear, please let me know.

Comment: @AkshayVasu : I may be thinking out loud but are you able to delete any line item records manually which is associated with history record ? I am assuming its a lookup relationship and Don't allow deletion of the lookup record that's part of a lookup relationship. is checked

Comment: @elijah The Record_Name__c field to which I am populating the Oli.Id is the text field and not the lookup field. And hence I guess It's not stopping me from deleting the line items. I tried using the trigger on the record that was created and owned by me. In this case, unlike the previous one, the history records were created successfully and line items got deleted successfully too. I guess this could have something to do with the Role Heirarchy. Could I be wrong in this?

Comment: @AkshayVasu : I don't think role hierarchy has anything to do with it as you are using without sharing and moreover you are logged in as system admin that means modify all data is true